# Why iterating Empty Map doesn't throw any exception in Java

Tags: java

I encountered the below code and I was expecting Java to through an exception as the List I am iterating is empty.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   final List<Map<String, Object>> candidateList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final Map<String, Object> candidate : candidateList) {
        if (candidate.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Empty!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

But the code execute without any Error or Exception being thrown.

Comment: Why did you expect an exception?

Comment: Java wouldn't throw an exception. It just wouldn't run your loop as the iterator would return `false` for `hasNext`. You would get an exception if `candidateList` is `null`

Comment: Consider: `int[] a = new int[0]; for (int n = 0; n < a.length; ++n) { }` Should that throw an error, too? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation

You are using the *enhanced for loop*:

```
for (final Map<String, Object> candidate : candidateList) {
    ...
}
```

The compiler replaces it with bytecode *equivalent* to the following source code:

```
Iterator<Map<String, Object>> elementIter = candidateList.iterator();
while (elementIter.hasNext()) {
    final Map<String, Object> candidate = elementIter.next();
    ...
}
```

While `elementIter.next()` will indeed throw a `NoSuchElementException` if there is no next element anymore (see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next())), the loop condition is checked first:

```
while (elementIter.hasNext()) {
```

And `Iterator#hasNext` returns `false` in your case. See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#hasNext()):

> Returns `true` if the iteration has more elements. (In other words, returns `true` if `next()` would return an element rather than throwing an exception.)

So your loop is **never entered**. Which is also why you won't see any exception, as desired by the designers of the loop.

---

### Comparison with regular loop

For a comparison, let's try to iterate an empty array with a regular loop:

```
int[] values = new int[0];

for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(values[i]);
}
```

The code runs fine, without any exception, for the same reason as before. The condition resolves to

```
i < 0
```

Which is already false for the first iteration (`i = 0`). So the loop is never entered.

Which means that the *enhanced for loop* behaves the same than this example for *regular loops*.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   final List<Map<String, Object>> candidateList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final Map<String, Object> candidate : candidateList) {
        //because all below code will never execute
        if (candidate.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Empty!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

It never go inside your loop, so it won't throw any exception.

if you add null element to your list. It will throw error

Answer (score 0):

The library designers decided to not throw an exception, because they thought this will make code that uses the library cleaner. If it did throw an exception, you'd had to check if the collection is empty every time, rather than just iterating it and rely on nothing happening.

Designers have made different decisions in different circumstances. For example, Guava's `Iterables.find(iterable, predicate)` throws an exception if no element exists that matches the predicate, when it could have just returned `null`, etc.

The rule of thumb used for deciding to throw an exception or not is this: if the invocation with the parameter is likely to have been made by error, or could create a hard to debug bug, then throw an exception. Otherwise do something sensible (like returning `null`, no-op etc.)

So, trying to iterate an empty collection was deemed to be not likely by error, whereas trying to find an element that doesn't exist in a collection was thought to be likely unintended, warranting an exception. But these are not hard and fast rules and the perspective differs from language to language, from designer to designer, and from case to case.